# limit of the q-exponential function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, q-analogs

We know that 
$$e_q(z)=\sum_{j\geq 0} \frac{z^j}{(q;q)_j}=\frac{1}{(z;q)_{\infty}}$$

where $(a;q)_{\infty}=\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}(1−aq^i)$ denotes the q-shifted factorial.

The limit between the $q$-exponential and the ordinary exponential is

$$\lim_{q\rightarrow1}e_q((1-q)z)=\lim_{q\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{((1-q)z;q)_{\infty}}=e^z.$$

My question is how to prove that

$$\lim_{q\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{(a\sqrt{q(1-q)};q)_{\infty}}=e^{\tfrac{-1}{2}a^2}?$$

I'm glad for your help.